# Google Cloud Vision IMAGE_PROPERTIES returns 10 colors/results no matter what image and what value for maxResults parameters

Tags: php, google-cloud-vision

I am new to Google Cloud Vision API and I wanted to extract the colors from an image using their dominant color functionality. below is my code which is base on [Terrence Ryan's Blog](http://terrenceryan.com/blog/index.php/working-with-cloud-vision-api-from-php/)

```
    $cvurl = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=API_KEY";

    $data = file_get_contents($cache_job);
    $base64 = base64_encode($data);
    //Create this JSON
    $r_json ='{
        "requests": [
            {
              "image": {
                "content":"' . $base64. '"
              },
              "features": [
                  {
                    "type": "IMAGE_PROPERTIES",
                    "maxResults": 200
                  }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $cvurl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $r_json);
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        die("Error: $cvurl failed status $status" );
    }
```

The code works but i got some issues with it. There are some colors that are obviously on the image but weren't included on the API response. And so I thought increasing the number of result will solve it but then i discovered that changing the "maxResults" (Google API docs: the number of results to be returned) parameter to any value does not affect anything on the response. The number of result are fixed to 10 colors even if I set the parameter to less than 10 and even if I change the image. Google's API documentation doesn't say anything about it so i was wondering if any of you guys here have experienced it.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this myself and I have the same results.
When doing **LABEL_DETECTION** and limiting the results to 1 for example, I do get 1 result.
Selecting **IMAGE_PROPERTIES** and reducing maxResults doesn't seem to impact the result.

I tried with a small image with few colors and only received 6 results however.
The results are structured this way:

```
           {
              "color": {
                "red": 198,
                "green": 218,
                "blue": 199
              },
              "score": 0.0016616513,
              "pixelFraction": 0.0016666667
            }
```

My guess is they have a cutoff point of the score where they drop the other results.

Just out of curiosity, why would you want to extract this many **dominant colors**? This isn't meant for extracting all colors from your image. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am creating an application that will help my users on selecting colors for their own webpage theme where they can upload an image or even a screenshot of another webpage in which i will extract the colors and add them to the user's choices of colors rather than just giving them a color wheel/picker. The thing is that sometimes even obvious colors are not returned/detected. An example is a screenshot of facebook's login page and the API's response doesn't even have the color blue in it which is the whole banner of the page.